# How did Rashi know Ben-Temalion was a small shed (שד)?

Tags: rashi, sheidim-demons, maseches-meila

In [Meilah 17b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Meilah.17b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&with=all&lang=he) there's a story about a  shed (שד) named Ben-Temalion who assisted Rashbi. Rashi there [writes](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Meilah.17b.5.1?lang=he):

> "בן תמליון - שד שקורין נוטיו"ן".

Translation: Ben-Temalion - a type of shed called a "nutiun".

According to [this list](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/leazey2/leazey12.pdf) of la'azei Rashi:

> "nutiun - little demon".

How did Rashi know that Ben-Temalion was a little shed?

Comment: Maybe you should spell it sheid or something like that in the title.  I thought it was going to be a Bava Basra type discussion and that you meant shed as in a little building where you keep your gardening tools.

Comment: @Heshy I spell it like that because that's how I pronounce it. I know it's not ideal as a Q title. I'll add the Hebrew.

Comment: @Heshy or how about shade, like the Greeks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because [Rabbeinu Gershom](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Gershom_on_Meilah.17b.7?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) before him gave a similar definition:

> יצא לקראתם בן תמליון. שד הוא שקורין טיטון

It is also worth noting the [Sefer HaAruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HeArukh%2C_Letter_Bet.243?vhe=Sefer_HeArukh,_Lublin_1883&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en), which served as a  dictionary of Talmudic and Midrashic words, who was a contemporary of Rashi. He writes there:

> בן תמליון - [נאהמע איין גייסטער] צא כיון דקרו ליה נפק (במעילה י"ז) פירוש שד

Comment: Ah, okay. Should I separately ask how Rabbeinu Gershon knew that?

Comment: I guess so. Although if you look on Sefaria this character בן תמליון appears several times in the Midrash.

Comment: I saw that only on one midrash. Strangely, the commentators there said that this Ben Temalion is a man, not a shed...

Comment: Refer to the Tosefta kifshuta on Shabbos - https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Kifshutah_on_Shabbat.7.22.4?vhe=Tosefta_Kifshuta._Third_Augmented_Edition,_JTS_2001&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en - ואין לוחשין בדבר שדים וכו', ולפי זה אינו אלא ללחוש להשביע שדים לצאת מן האיש, כדרך בן תמליון (מעילה י"ז ב'), ור' יוסי אוסר שמא יזיק אותו כשמוציאין אותו בעל כרחו.

Comment: Although on reflection the Tosefta Kifshuta which serves as a commentary on the Tosefta there on Shabbos is a much later commentary - but I guess worthwhile noting another source.

Comment: Also worth noting that the reference of this shed also appears in a variant form as תְּלַמְיוֹן which appears in other midrashim