# How is it known that Ben-Temalion was a small shed (שד)?

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, sheidim-demons, maseches-meila

A follow-up to my [first question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127177/how-did-rashi-know-ben-temalion-was-a-small-shed), which is really what I was going for on that question:

How is it known that Ben-Temalion was a small shed (שד)?

@Dov sourced Rashi to Rabbeinu Gershom, but that doesn't tell me how it's known what sort of shed he was.

Comment: Presumably the explanation was passed down through the generations.

Comment: Because it's a "ben-" a son of something. That would imply there  is a larger version of it.

Comment: @ClintEastwood fascinating suggestion. I wonder what temalion means.